# Utilizar RegexIterator em diretórios para encontrar pasta ou arquivo

Tags: php

Não sou muito bom com regex e preciso de uma ajuda para fazer uma especie de pesquisa entre arquivos a partir de parte do nome da pasta ou arquivo que fica no final

```
$find = 'oo';
$directory = 'd:\\test';
    $search = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
        );


    $search = new RegexIterator($search, '/'.$find.'/i');
```

Pastas e arquivos no diretorio:

```
d:\test\bar foo;
d:\test\foo bar;
d:\test\text.txt;
d:\test\foo.txt;
```

O objetivo é encontrar pastas ou arquivos partes com `oo`

```
d:\test\foo bar;
d:\test\bar foo;
d:\test\foo.txt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Há algum tempo atrás eu precisei fazer uma busca parecida com a sua, utilizei o código abaixo para resolver o problema:

```
<?php

function listarArquivos($diretorio, $nomeArquivo) {
    $encontrados = "";
    $ponteiro = opendir($diretorio);

    while ($nome_itens = readdir($ponteiro)) {
        $itens[] = $nome_itens;
    }

    sort($itens);

    foreach ($itens as $listar) {
        if ($listar != "." && $listar != "..") {
            if (is_dir($diretorio . '/' . $listar)) {
                $encontrados .= listarArquivos($diretorio . '/' . $listar, $nomeArquivo);
            } else {
                if (preg_match('/' . $nomeArquivo . '/i', $listar)) {
                    $encontrados .= $diretorio . '/' . $listar . " <br> ";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $encontrados;
}

try {

    echo listarArquivos('C:\www\layout', "(nome)*(ou)*(partes)");

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Eu testei e funcionou, mas quero fazer o uso do RecursiveIteratorIterator por ser mais rápido, mesmo que por milésimos

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar o seguinte código:

```
<?php 

$find = 'min';
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('C:\www\layout');
$flattened = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);

$files = new RegexIterator($flattened, '/'.$find.'/i');

foreach($files as $file) {
    echo $file . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
}
```

Retirei daqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321547/how-to-use-regexiterator-in-php

Comment: tem um problema, ao pesquisar a pasta, no loop acaba mostrando todos seus arquivos que não possuem nenhuma parte da string de pesquisa

Comment: na verdade, ele vai ler todos os diretórios da sua pasta base e vai pegar o caminho inteiro do arquivo e verificar se existe o que vc está pesquisando. Exemplo: "C:\www\layout\MIN.txt" e "C:\www\layout\MINimo\algumacoisa.txt".